# Macro in blender? Quick way to set 1 hotkey for "Rotate 90 degrees" in UV editor?

Tags: uv, shortcut, uv-image-editor

Anyone knows how to set a single hotkey for "rotate 90 degrees" in UV editor?

Comment: Rotate once then use Shift+R? If aligning rotation to another island then possible with [UV Align Distribute](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?340206-Add-On-UV-Align-Distribute) addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't *think* there's a built in way to do this, so a while ago I created an add-on called *[UV Rotate Shortcuts](https://github.com/RayMairlot/UV-Rotate-Shortcuts)*.

This adds <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to rotate the selected UVs by 90 degrees or -90 degrees respectively.

The rotation amount can be customised in the add-on's user preferences.

Comment: Dude, I am not 100% sure, but I think you have a problem in your git package: the "UV Rotate.py" file should be called "UV_Rotate.py". I could not find it in "User Preferences/Addons" untill I renamed it. Afterwards I also changed the code on line 100 to make "UV Rotate" into "UV_Rotate" in order to make things work. I might have made a mistake somwhere, but that is my experience. In any case, now everything is working and I am very grateful to you.

Comment: Yeah, one more thing. Your action does not register as a reversible command, so sometimes one can get into trouble with Ctrl+Z-ting, but otherwise, man, where have you been all mah life? :)

Comment: @cubrman I've now updated the add-on to allow undoing. This was a silly mistake on my part. As for the renaming, people have been known to have trouble installing the zips downloaded from github (not just with my add-on). Unzip first, if that's what you did, and just install the .py.

Comment: I did unzip, and copied the .py in the required forlder (Win PC), for some reason Blender did not show the addon in the list. Anyway, thanks for undoing!

Comment: Ok I can confirm that now everything works without any renaming and you can successfully undo rotation commands, thanks man!