# Rotate UVs 90 Degrees Shortcut

Tags: uv-image-editor

Anyone clever enough to figure out a way to assign a shortcut to rotate UV islands by -/+ 90 degrees (Blender 2.8)?

I found the transform.rotate shortcut, which works great when you type in 90 into the angle field. But then you have to confirm it with a second button after. I was wondering if anyone knows of a trick to auto-confirm or something similar? I was trying to rig the shortcuts as Ctrl + Mouse Wheel up/down. Key presses work a little better because you can use the release event to confirm. Still a little sketchy.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Exact same question, but I haven't updated the add-on to work with 2.80 yet: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81564/macro-in-blender-quick-way-to-set-1-hotkey-for-rotate-90-degrees-in-uv-editor

Comment: Yeah, I tried that add-on before I posted. Didn't have any luck getting it to work in 2.8.

Comment: @RayMairlot I can only say that it works fine here in 2.8 and currently 2.81 (which I am using). It looks like the op also has it working if he has ticked the answer.

Comment: @ barkest: I believe Ray was referring to a different addon (https://github.com/RayMairlot/UV-Rotate-Shortcuts). One he created, I believe. I tried to get it to work on 2.8, but didn't get very far. TexTools works great in 2.8. Although there appears to be an issue when trying to use it with multiple objects selected (in edit mode with 2+ objects). Hopefully they will upgrade that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use TexTools addon. It was 2.79 but someone ported it to 2.8 and it works pretty well

[image]

as you can see it has a -90 and +90 which you can assign a shortcut key to if required

here is the download

https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender/releases/download/TexTools_2.80/textools.zip

Comment: This is a perfect solution